# LinearProgramming behavior

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Consider the following linear programming problem:

```
LinearProgramming[-{10, -57, -9, -24}, -( {
     {0.5, -5.5, 2.5, 9},
     {0.5, -1.5, -.5, 1},
     {1, 0, 0, 0}
    } ), -{0, 0, 1}]
 (* {0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
```

Why is this answer being returned? Taking $\textbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^T$ satisfies $\textbf{x}\ge 0\land A\textbf{x}\ge \textbf{b}$, but the value of the objective function for this solution is $-1$, which is clearly smaller than $0$, the suggested "optimal" solution by *Mathematica*.

I would expect *Mathematica* to be able to solve such a small LP problem, even if it is degenerate. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at what `LinearProgramming` does: it finds a vector `x` that minimizes the quantity `c.x` subject to the constraints `m.x>=b` and `x>=0`. For your candidate answer `x={1,0,1,0}`, the product `m.x` is equal to `{-3., 0., -1.}`, which is not greater than your `b={0, 0, -1}`. Hence this is not a valid solution. Indeed, `x={0,0,0,0}` is the best you can get given the constraints.

Comment: The issue was that I missed a sign when inputting the values